# how can i solve this htaccess problem

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have following dynamic url...

```
http://www.mydomain.com/v/dynamicvaluehere
```

and i have following in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^v/(.*)$ script.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

and it is working fine now i want to create further i.e

```
http://www.mydomain.com/v/dynamicvaluehere/Page-dyanamicnumberhere.html
```

and i have following in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^v/(.*)/Page-(.*)\.html$ script.php?name=$1&number=$2 [NC,L]
```

but it is not working please help...
also do note that the dynamicvalue mentnioned secondly is samy as mentioned above but only dynamicnumber is further included...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be your use of wildcards. If your .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^v/(.*)$ script.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^v/(.*)/Page-(.*)\.html$ script.php?name=$1&number=$2 [NC,L]
```

then no pattern will ever reach the second argument because `(.*)/Page-(.*)\.html` will actually fall under `(.*)` first.

You could either refine your wildcards to something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^v/([A-Za-z0-9].*)$ script.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^v/([A-Za-z0-9].*)/Page-([0-9].*)\.html$ script.php?name=$1&number=$2 [NC,L]
```

or maybe even try switching the order of your statements to:

```
RewriteRule ^v/(.*)/Page-(.*)\.html$ script.php?name=$1&number=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^v/(.*)$ script.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second rule is never being reached because of the *greedy* nature of the first. You can either put it above the first rule or make your first rule more specific.

Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^v/(.+)/Page-(.+)\.html$ script.php?name=$1&number=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^v/(.*)$ script.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```